# Starting AWS elastic mapreduce jobflow from Java API. Where should my hive script go?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, hive, elastic-map-reduce

I have been developing a data processing application using Amazon Elastic MapReduce and Hive. Now that my Hive scripts work when I SSH and run them using the Interactive Mode Job Flow, I'm trying to create a Job Flow using the AWS Java API.

Using http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/calling-emr-with-java-sdk.html as my starting point, I create a step config like this

```
StepConfig runScript = new StepConfig().withName("Prepare Admin")
.withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
.withHadoopJarStep(oStepFactory.newRunHiveScriptStep(scriptPath, args));
```

I assumed/hope that scriptPath can be an s3 url to my Hive script, like: s3://bucketName/hive-script. The only documentation I've found talks about using a script from the master node's file system. But if the master node is an instance started for the sake of this Job Flow, I don't understand how I can get any script (Hive or otherwise) onto the file system.

When I try my idea (passing an s3 location to the stepFactory method), the runScript step fails.

I've checked the logs via the AWS console. The stdout logs end with

2012-11-19 19:28:33 GMT - ERROR Error executing cmd: /home/hadoop/.versions/hive-0.7.1/bin/hive '-f' 's3://anet-emr/scripts/admin.q' '-d rawDataLocation=s3://anet-emr/raw -d year=2010 -d cycle=1'

The stderr logs end with

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine.getOptionProperties(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Properties;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.OptionsProcessor.process_stage1(OptionsProcessor.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.run(JobShell.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.main(JobShell.java:68)

and the Controller log has

2012-11-19T19:28:27.406Z INFO Executing /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java -cp /home/hadoop/conf:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/lib/tools.jar:/home/hadoop:/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.18-core.jar:/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.18-tools.jar:/home/hadoop/lib/*:/home/hadoop/lib/jetty-ext/* -Xmx1000m -Dhadoop.log.dir=/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/3 -Dhadoop.log.file=syslog -Dhadoop.home.dir=/home/hadoop -Dhadoop.id.str=hadoop -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,DRFA -Djava.io.tmpdir=/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/3/tmp -Djava.library.path=/home/hadoop/lib/native/Linux-i386-32 org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell /mnt/var/lib/hadoop/steps/3/script-runner.jar s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script --base-path s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/ --hive-versions latest --run-hive-script --args -f s3://anet-emr/scripts/admin.q -d rawDataLocation=s3://anet-emr/raw -d year=2010 -d cycle=1
2012-11-19T19:28:34.143Z INFO Execution ended with ret val 255
2012-11-19T19:28:34.143Z WARN Step failed with bad retval

The problem seems to lie with the arguments I'm passing via Amazon's API to Hive's call to the Apache CLI library... I've tried passing a single string with "-d arg1=val1 -d arg2=val2", I've tried "-d,arg1=val1 etc.." and I've tried various ways of chopping up into String arrays - ie { "-d", "arg1=val1" ...}. Can't find any documentation of the proper way to do this!

Any help appreciated, thank you
Coleman

Comment: I had a problem with the args[] being generated in Java. Where my command had been this: /home/hadoop/.versions/hive-0.7.1/bin/hive '-f' 's3://anet-emr/scripts/admin.q' '-d rawDataLocation=s3://anet-emr/raw -d year=2010 -d cycle=1' it should have been this /home/hadoop/.versions/hive-0.7.1/bin/hive '-f' 's3://anet-emr/scripts/admin.q' '-d' 'rawDataLocation=s3://anet-emr/raw' '-d' 'year=2010' '-d' 'cycle=1'

Answer (score 1):

Hi this code works for me:

```
String accessKey = "";
String secretKey = "";
 AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
   AmazonElasticMapReduceClient emr = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(credentials);

   StepFactory stepFactory = new StepFactory();

   StepConfig enabledebugging = new StepConfig()
       .withName("Enable debugging")
       .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
       .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newEnableDebuggingStep());

   StepConfig installHive = new StepConfig()
       .withName("Install Hive")
       .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
       .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newInstallHiveStep());

   StepConfig runScript = new StepConfig()
        .withName("Run Script")
        .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
        .withHadoopJarStep(stepFactory.newRunHiveScriptStep("s3://dummy/dummy.hive"));


   RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
       .withName("Hive Interactive")
       .withSteps(enabledebugging, installHive, runScript)
       .withLogUri("s3://dummy/")
       .withInstances(new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
           .withHadoopVersion("0.20.205")
           .withInstanceCount(1)
           .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(false)
           .withMasterInstanceType("m1.small")
           .withSlaveInstanceType("m1.small"));

   RunJobFlowResult result = emr.runJobFlow(request);
```

Hope this helps :)